# trying to fetch data with fetch and promise, doesnt work (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to get data out of an API with fetch, I can `console.log` the result in the fetch but out of the fetch I can't reach the data.

So I got this fetchData.js file with the function in it:

```
export const fetchData = (url) => {
    
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

and then in the app.jsx file I call the function like this:

```
import { fetchData } from "./fetchData";

const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"

function App() {
  let data = fetchData(URL);
  console.log(data);

//return etc
```

But the `console.log(data)` keeps saying "undefined".

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You're calling an async function and then not waiting for it to return before checking its value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That's true, but he should have seen a `Promise` in the log.  Try removing the second `then`, i.e. `.then(result => console.log(result))`.  It's returning `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the asynchronous action to complete before logging it.

```
let data = fetchData(URL).then(() => {console.log(data);});
```

(also either remove `then(result => console.log(result))` or return result from it)

Comment: this will give me an error 
"App.jsx:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

`fetchData` is an `async` function, that is why the console.log is executed before fetchData is resolved:

```
export const fetchData = async (url) => {  
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => (result)) //--> data
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

then in component, inside useEffect:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]) //--> keep data in component state
  
  useEffect(()=> {
     fetchData(URL) //--> fetch data when component is mounted
      .then(response => setData(response))
  }, []);
  //...
}
```

Comment: aah yes this is working! only weird thing is when i put {data} in the return its gives an error but console.log(data) is working ?

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {devices}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: How are you render the content? check if data has the format that you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

1. Change
   `.then(result => console.log(result))` to `.then(result => {return result})`
2. `fetchData(URL).then((data) => {console.log(data);});`

The returned result will be put in data which can then be logged.